# Laravel eloquent Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi so here are my relation:

Location:

```
public function _geoloc()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\GeoLoc',  'id');
}
```

Geoloc:

```
public function locations()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Location', 'geoloc_id');
}
```

Controller:

```
    $geoloc = new Geoloc;
    $geoloc->lat = $request->input('lat');
    $geoloc->lng = $request->input('lng');
    $geoloc->save();
    $geoloc_id = $geoloc->id;

    $location = new Location;
    $location->business_id = $business_id;
    $location->latitude = $request->input('lat');
    $location->longitude = $request->input('lng');
    $location->slug = $request->input('name');
    $location->geoloc_id = $geoloc_id;
    $location->save();
```

Full error message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`liveoldham`.`locations`, CONSTRAINT `locations_geoloc_id_foreign`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`geoloc_id`) REFERENCES `geoloc` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
>   ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `locations` (`business_id`,
>   `latitude`, `longitude`, `slug`, `geoloc_id`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (1, 53.4867546, -2.054066599999942, Live & Now,
>   94, 2017-06-27 15:22:51, 2017-06-27 15:22:51))

All the values are correct, row is inserted into geoloc but it doesn't get inserted to locations and this is the error I am gettiing, how can that be fixed?

//edit:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateLocationsTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('locations', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('business_id')->unsigned();
            $table->float('latitude', 10,6);
            $table->float('longitude', 10,6);
            $table->integer('geoloc_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('slug', 29)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('locations');
    }
}
```

2nd:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateGeolocTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
            Schema::create('_geoloc', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->float('lat', 10,6);
            $table->float('lng', 10,6);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('_geoloc');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the associate method when updating a belongsTo relationship.
So, instead of

```
$location->geoloc_id = $geoloc_id;
```

Use

```
$location->_geoloc()->associate($geoloc);
$location->save();
```

Also make sure your belongsTo & hasOne have correct ForeignKey as second parameter.

According to your migration,

Your Location Model should have

```
public function _geoloc()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\GeoLoc',  'geoloc_id');
}
```

Also, I don't see you setting a foreign key relationship using migration itself. So update your `CreateLocationsTable` to:

```
$table->integer('geoloc_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('geoloc_id')->references('id')->on('_geoloc')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Now you should re-run your migrations and it will work.

Comment: I now get: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'geoloc_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `locations` (`business_id`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `slug`, `id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (4, 53.4867546, -2.054066599999942, Live & Now, 97, 2017-06-27 15:46:32, 2017-06-27 15:46:32))

Comment: The insert query is looking for field called 'id' instead of 'geoloc_id'. It should be `belongsTo('App\GeoLoc',  'geoloc_id');`. I will have to look into your table structure for geoloc and locations. It would be better if you post your migration for these two.

Comment: I did that and it didn't work I got the same error as in the question